# How to show transaction isolation level (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, isolation-level

I want to know what isolation level is set for current Mysql database. How can find it out? I tried searching it on the google but did not find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a bit of more searching on the google and found out that if have MySQL 5.1+ then you can find out the isolation level by firing below query

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'tx_isolation';
```

Comment: Note that this answer is outdated. See the other answers for MySQL 8.

Answer (score 37):

check session transaction level (mysql8+)

```
SELECT @@transaction_ISOLATION;
```

check global transaction level (mysql8+)

```
SELECT @@global.transaction_ISOLATION;
```

Comment: is ```@@global.transaction_ISOLATION ``` the current session variable?

Comment: Wait a second, it's the other way round, right? `@@global.` is the global one.

Answer (score 23):

There are potentially six different transaction isolation level values in MySQL/MariaDB - and they could have different values. They are:

1. Value defined in the configuration file(s).
2. Value used in the command line option used to start *mysqld*.
3. The global transaction isolation level.
4. The session transaction isolation level.
5. The level that will be used by the very next transaction that is created.
6. The level being used by the current transaction.

The reason you want to know its value, will determine which one (or multiple ones) you need.

Also, be aware of when the level that was obtained can change - sometimes by things outside your control.

**1. Configured level**

Look for a `transaction-isolation` entry in the configuration files. This may be found under sections such as `[mysqld]` or `[server]`.

Start with the default */etc/my.cnf*, but you may have to look in other configuration files depending on the include statements used. Be aware that *mysqld* might be started with command line options telling it to ignore the configuration files or to use a different set of configuration files.

**2. Command line option level**

Examine how the *mysqld* process was started. The level used here will override any specified in the configuration files.

It may change if *mysqld* is somehow started differently in the future.

**3. Global level**

This can be retrieved by running `SELECT @@global.tx_isolation;`.

This is initially set when the database starts up, to the level provided by the command line option or from the configuration file.

It can be changed by running `set GLOBAL transaction isolation level ...`. But be aware that any value set that way will be lost when the database restarts. It could change if some other program runs the *set global* command.

**4. Session level**

This can be retrieved by running `SELECT @@tx_isolation;`.

When a new session/connection is created, it is set to the current global level.

It can be changed by running `set SESSION transaction isolation level ...` in that session.

If you are using connection pools, be aware that its value could change on you (reverting back to the global level), since connections can be silently terminated and re-established if it is put back into the pool.

**5. Next transaction level**

There is no way to query this.

This level is set by running `set transaction isolation level ...` and that level will override the session level and global level for the very next transaction created in that session. The next transaction after that will revert back to using the session level (unless another *set transaction isolation level* command is issued again).

To know this value, you'll have to keep track of how you've used *set transaction isolation level* (if you've used it at all).

**6. Current transaction level**

There is no way to query this. (It is the subject of [MySQL bug #53341](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53341).)

To know this value, you'll have to infer what it is from the session level (at the time the transaction was created) and if you had set the "next transaction level" immediately before you created the transaction.

**References**

- Set transaction in MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/
- Transaction isolation levels in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Answer (score 13):

I use the following snippet:

```
mysql> SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;
+-----------------+
| @@TX_ISOLATION  |
+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 11):

**MySQL 8+**

`SELECT @@transaction_isolation;        -- session`

`SELECT @@global.transaction_isolation; -- global`

According to MySQL 8 [Deprecation notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-3.html#mysqld-8-0-3-deprecation-removal):

> The deprecated tx_isolation and tx_read_only system variables have
> been removed. Use transaction_isolation and transaction_read_only
> instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
SELECT DATABASE();      to verify you are using the database, then
SELECT @TX_ISOLATION;    for the DB TX isolation value
SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;   for global TX isolation value
```

if your db verification is not what you think it should be,

```
USE [db-you-want-to-check];
SELECT DATABASE();    to verify current database, then
SELECT @TX_ISOLATION;   for current database TX isolation value
SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;   for GLOBAL TX isolation value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one another query grammer:

```
MariaDB root@127.0.0.1:mysql> show variables like '%tx%'
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| tx_isolation  | REPEATABLE-READ |
| tx_read_only  | OFF             |
+---------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set
Time: 0.006s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show session isolation level. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937472/how-to-set-transaction-isolation-level-mysql#73708826) explains how to set transaction isolation level:

```sql
SELECT @@SESSION.transaction_isolation;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT @@transaction_isolation;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'transaction_isolation';
```

And, you can show global isolation level:

```sql
SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation;
```

In addition, you can show persisted isolation level if it exists

```sql
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.persisted_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'transaction_isolation';
```